# Laravel Sanctum API identify user that is trying to post a Note

Tags: laravel

So I'm new to Laravel and I've made Login/Signup page to work with React SPA and Laravel Backend, the problem is i don't know now to post to database only for that user, I mean to add a note for that user, How can i do that, how the backend will know that, what is method around that?

Comment: Did the below answer solve your issue? If so, please may you mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Sanctum provides middlewares to authenticate the requests coming to a route. For that, first, you should validate the user-credentials and generate the token as specified [here in the doucmentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#issuing-mobile-api-tokens).

```
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

Route::post('/sanctum/token', function (Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'device_name' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if (! $user || ! Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
        ]);
    }

    return $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;
});
```

This route validates the user credentials and creates a token. You should include this token in the subsequent requests.

Then protect your routes by including the `auth:sanctum` middleware.

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Now the `$request->user()` should return the current authenticated user.

Also read about [SPA-Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authentication).
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authentication